# Flash CS3 went into wireframe mode: Why, and how can I stop it?

Tags: adobe-flash, adobe-cs3

I have no idea how I did it, but I bumped Flash CS3 into some wireframe mode, and after looking high and low can't figure out how to disable.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I figured it out. There is a little checkbox in the layers tool that, when hovered over, says "Show all layers as outlines." I must've accidentally clicked it.

Comment: Dont forget to mark this as the correct answer in 48 hours

Answer (score 0):

Try  Apple + T/ Ctrl + T? I'm not sure if this goes across through all the Creative Suite Apps, but in Illustrator, when you press Ctrl + T, it goes into draft/wireframe mode.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no dice :(

Answer (score -1):

Issue came up Animate 2017 Mac was stuck in outline mode for all instances on stage ( stroke, fill, bitmap import) all just showed as outline ( despite toggling the obvious timeline "outline" view on or off.. no change

Found the fix here:  From top menu bar go to VIEW>Preview mode> had been set to "outline"
Switch that to "fast" preview mode and the problem is resolved.
Kathleen Quaife